# I am departing on an Air India flight from KTM before the Thai Airways lounge opens. Is there another lounge I can use?

Tags: air-travel, airports, air-india, ktm

I am departing on an Air India flight from KTM at 10:35 am in business class. From what I found, I can access the Thai Royal Silk lounge but, according to the [Thai website](http://www.thaiairways.com/en_TH/exp_thai/Airport_Services/royal_orchid_lounges.page#div8-section1), the lounge only opens at 10:00 am. Since the lounge is located before security, this means I will not be able to access the lounge.

Is there any other lounge I can access at the airport?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the [Executive Lounge](https://www.loungeclub.com/en/our-lounges/lounge-detail/KTM), which opens at 6. It's landside too, and it looks like access is paid or through Priority Pass.